# How to prepare a Mac installer for my java swing application

Tags: java, swing, macos, installation

Can anybody give me suggestions about preparing a custom Mac Installer for a Java swing application. I have tried Xcode but of no use. Any suggestions would be really helpful.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you actually need an installer? Unless you need to put files in very specific locations and need admin privileges for that, installers are uncommon on the Mac. Typically, you'd use a disk image with a self-contained application bundle. See my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/368022/which-one-is-better-dmg-or-packagemaker/368141#368141). That answer also mentions how to create a standard OS X installer.

Comment: Does the package maker for mac is avilable as an open source Software?

Comment: Hi jackrabbit i saw ur answer but i wanted to know whether package maker for mac is available for free?

Comment: It is bundled with XCode. On my machine, it is located in /Developer/Applications/Utilities. Come to think of it, for Java applications, Jar Bundler is probably more appropriate: /usr/share/java/Tools/Jar Bundler

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [http://izpack.org](http://izpack.org/).

> IzPack-generated installers only require a Java virtual machine to run. It is fully cross-platform and generates a single installer. As such, it is an alternative to native solutions like as platform-specific installers and package managers.

Or for a more Mac-specific option, see this 10-step tutorial:

- [http://www.centerkey.com/mac/java](http://www.centerkey.com/mac/java/) (Updated for Mac OS X 10.6 — Snow Leopard)

Comment: hey thanks for the reply...Can i create a custom installer using this izpack.Like After installation a folder "X" should be created in application folder and the folder "X" should have subfolder "Y".How can i achieve this